# Not respecting if statement

Tags: if-statement, unity-game-engine, runtime-error

I have this code that is supposed to fade out the rotating yellow cube once the ball triggers the collision.
But once the alpha reaches **0**, it continues one more time until the alpha reaches **-0.200** and the cube becomes blue before disappearing.

```c#
if (disapear)
{
    if (rndr.material.color.a > 0.0f)
    {
        rndr.material.color -= new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.2f);
        Debug.Log(rndr.material.color);
    }
    else
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

[image: finish line]

[image: Screenshot 2]

EDIT: There is no problem for the red finish line which uses the same code.

EDIT2: On the second screenshot I managed to find the value of **a** before it becomes **-0.200**, which is **2.980232E-08**. I don't really know what it means.

Comment: I haven't messed with Unity, but you may try putting a break point on the inside if and see what rndr.material.color.a evaluates to, that may give you an idea on how to solve the issue.

Comment: Also, the tag syntax-error would mean that the application will not run, this is a run-time error.

Comment: I found 2,980232E-08 as the value of the alpha before it becomes -0.200, what does it mean ?

Comment: That number is greater than 0, I would think that you could use DarceVader's answer to fix this (depending on what you are doing you may want to check >= 0.2f).

Comment: it could be the alpha is constrain between 0 and 1 so it never really gets below 0 and you luckily gets a glitch under 0. It is probable the value is clamp so if below 0 it gets to exact 0. you could try to compare with <= 0 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because the value of alpha when it gets close to 0f might not exactly be 0 (i.e. 0.0000001 > 0.0f), I'd make your boolean be `if (rndr.material.color.a > 0.2f)` or set the alpha value to 0 under else

Answer (score 2):

This happens due to [single floating point precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

=> Never compare two `float` values directly.

---

You should use e.g. [Mathf.Approximately](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html)

```
if(Mathf.Approximately(rndr.material.color.a, 0))
```

Comment: All of the answers posted here are technically correct, but this is the preferred solution, as Unity's `Mathf.Approximately` does the comparison for you using an Epsilon value you don't have to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

The value 2.980232E-08 is lower than Machine epsilon see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon for a float.

Most certainly it arrose when successively substracting 0.2f from 1.0f (5 times).
Most likely 1.0f -5.0f*0.2f ~ 2.980232E-08f

Therefore you should change the way you implement the function, maybe add an `increment_to_disappear` `(int)` along with your `disapear`  property :

```
if (disapear)
{
    if (increment_to_disappear < 5)
    {
        rndr.material.color -= new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.2f);
        increment_to_disappear++;
    }
    else
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

}
```